# Limit identity for $f''(x)$ proof

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, proof-verification

Problem statement:

Let $f: (a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be given. If $f''(x)$ exists, prove that $$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x-h)-2f(x)+f(x+h)}{h^2} = f''(x).$$

---

### Is the following reasoning correct?

Consider the following facts:

\begin{align}
\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} f(x + h) &= \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} f(x + 2h) \\
\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} f(x + h) &= f(x) = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} f(x) \\
\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} f(x - h) &= f(x) = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} f(x) \\
\end{align}

It follows as such:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h) - 2f(x) + f(x-h)}{h^2} &= 
\frac{\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}f(x+h) - 2\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}f(x) + \lim_{h \rightarrow 0}f(x-h)}{\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}h^2} \\ &= \frac{\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}f(x+2h) - 2\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}f(x+h) + \lim_{h \rightarrow 0}f(x)}{\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}h^2} \\ &= \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+2h) - 2f(x+h) + f(x)}{h^2} \\ &= \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{\frac{f(x+2h) - 2f(x+h) + f(x)}{h}}{h} \\ &= \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{\frac{f(x+2h) - f(x+h)}{h} - \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}}{h} \\ &= \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+2h) - f(x+h)}{h} - \lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}}{h} \\ &= \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f'(x+h) - f'(x)}{h} \\ &= f''(x)
\end{align*}

Comment: I thought I didn't have to mention it because of the "proof verification" tab. Sorry guys.

Comment: Formally, you have an error right at the start: you cannot insert the limit into the fraction.

Comment: A better approach is to go for L'Hospital's Rule but use it only once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Taylor-Young formula,

$$f(x+h)=f(x)+hf'(x)+\frac{h^2}{2}f''(x)+h^2\epsilon_1(x)$$

$$f(x-h)=f(x)-hf'(x)+\frac{h^2}{2}f''(x)+h^2\epsilon_2(x)$$

sum and finish.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument fails here:
$$
\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h) - 2f(x) + f(x-h)}{h^2} = 
\frac{\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}f(x+h) - 2\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}f(x) + \lim_{h \rightarrow 0}f(x-h)}{\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}h^2}
$$
that is at the first step.

The right hand side is $0/0$, which is undefined.

The arguments you're using later are similarly wrong. Consider
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x-\sin x}{x^3}=
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\lim_{x\to0}(x-\sin x)}{x^3}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{0}{x^3}=0
$$
Sorry, the limit is $1/6$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and furthermore you can skip the first two steps by performing substitution
\begin{align*} u = x + h \end{align*}

Comment: This answer could use a bit of clarification. Was is supposed to answer a comment? The attempt in the question has the error of placing limit inside the fraction. And I don't see why this substitution would help.