# Can the second derivative be written this way?

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives

I was watching a YouTube video about a problem and the guy in it used this equation, and I'm not sure if it's true can anyone help?

$f"(x)= \frac{f(x+h)-2f(x)+f(x-h)}{h^2} $

link of video if it helps https://youtu.be/K8bItucbISA: min 4:56

Comment: Only if you add a limit: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2992985/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3334506/42969

Comment: can't possibly be true since the RHS depends on $h$ but the LHS does not. What's true is that the limit of the RHS as $h\to0$ is the LHS (under appropriate hypotheses...)

Answer (score 1):

Should be this
$$
f''(x)= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-2f(x)+f(x-h)}{h^2}
\tag1$$
Perhaps you can prove these properties yourself:
If $f''(x)$ exists, then the limit on the right exists, and they are equal.
It is possible that the limit on the right exists, but $f''(x)$ does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Taylor expansion up to second order:
$$f(x+h)=f(x)+hf'(x)+\frac{h^2}2f''(x)$$
Similarly, you can write $$f(x-h)=f(x)-hf'(x)+\frac{h^2}2f''(x)$$
Adding the two equations together and keeping $f''(x)$ on one side yields your desired formula. Note that this is exactly true only if the function $f$ is at most a quadratic polynomial. Otherwise is just an approximation (that would work for many functions in the limit $h\to 0$).

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, the second derivative is rendered:

$f''(x)=\underset{h_1\to0}{\lim}\dfrac{f'(x+h_1)-f'(x)}{h_1}=\underset{(h_1,h_2)\to(0,0)}{\lim}\dfrac{f(x+h_1+h_2)-f(x+h_1)-f(x+h_2)+f(x)}{h_1h_2}.$ ... Eq. 1

This is a more stringent condition than the one given in the question

$f''(x)=\underset{h\to0}{\lim}\dfrac{f(x+h)-2f(x)-f(x-h)}{h^2},$ ... Eq. (2)

because the two increments in the former must be allowed to vary independently. It is indeed possible that the limit exists when we specify $h_1=-h_2=h$, which converts Eq. (1) to Eq. (2), but that does not always guarantee that the limit continues to exist and give the same value with other possible $(h_1,h_2)$ paths.

Comment: Does existence of your limit in equation 1 mean that $f$ is second differentiable?  Could you show me how it implies existence of the first derivatives?

Comment: Note the intermediate stage, first derivatives must exist to move on to the final form.

Comment: Sure, I understand the implication in that direction.  I am wondering the reverse:  can that limit exist while the first derivative fails to exist, or fails to be differentiable?

Comment: Attempting to use my Eq. 1 when the first derivative does not exist will result in not having a well-defined second derivative. Try it with, for instance, various $(h_1,h_2)$ paths for $f(x)=|x|$. Eq. 2 which is inferior would appear to give a limit of $0$.

Comment: You show that there are examples of the eq 1 limit not existing and also first derivative does not exist.  I ask for examples where eqn 1 does exist, but f is not differentiable.

Comment: @StevenGubkin I cannot think of any, and there may be a good reason ... .